# Remove all the array values from the string efficiently, if array value is part of a word in the string whole word must also be removed from string

Tags: php

I have an array of strings

```
$array = array("are", "finite", "get", "er");
```

and a string

```
$string = "You are definitely getting better today";
```

I expect this output

```
You today
```

I want to remove all the array values from the string efficiently, if array value is part of a word in the string whole word must also be removed from string.

Here is my code on which I am working at the moment

```
foreach ($array as $a)
{
    $string = str_replace($a, "", $string);
}
echo $string;
```

It removes array values from the string, but it do not remove words that contain array values.

**Edit:**

As my strings are user provided and are about 4096 characters long, someone please guide me which answer is more efficient with respect of speed and memory usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (regex approach):

```
$patterns = ["are", "finite", "get", "er"];
$string = "You are definitely getting better today";

$re = '\w*('.implode('|', $patterns).')\w*';
$string = preg_replace('#'.$re.'#', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('#\h{2,}#', ' ', $string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Is it more efficient with respect of speed and memory usage

Comment: As Gordon said you need to benchmark solutions yourself in your server config / context, because optimization depends on many relative factors. In your place I would construct typical-length string and typical-search-pattern list and pass modified versions of solutions with _for loop_ for let's say 1000 retries through a Linux `time` command and see the results.

Comment: What changes are need in your provided code if $patterns are coma separated list e.g. **are,finite,get,er**

Comment: coma separated words in a string or what ? - give exact example. (I already gave you snippet with word list - `[]` is syntactic sugar for `array()` which I prefer mostly)

Comment: I mean if I provide **$patterns ="are,finite,get,er";** instead of **$patterns = ["are", "finite", "get", "er"];**

Comment: Use explode() to convert string to an array:  
`$patterns = explode("," , $patterns);`

Comment: I have coma separated list saved in database, I want to simplify the process, instead of using explode and than implode want to use the list directly as patterns.

Comment: You have to 1. either construct regex from modifying pattern string in-place by a) explode/implode b) str_replace. In any case this is an extra step as you said. I suggest solution 2. save whole regex formula in database, i.e. `\w*(are|finite|get|er)\w*` can be saved in some db column

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version with [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok)

```
$patterns = ["are", "finite", "get", "er"];
$string = "You are definitely getting better today";

$tok = strtok($string, ' ');
while ($tok !== false) {
    foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
        if (strpos($tok, $pattern) !== FALSE) {
            $string = str_replace("$tok ", '', $string);
        }
    }
    $tok = strtok(' ');
}
echo $string;
```

And here is another regex version:

```
$string = "You are definitely getting better today";
$patterns = ["are", "finite", "get", "er"];

$regex = sprintf(
    "#\w*(%s)\w*\h*#",
    implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $patterns))
);
echo preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
```

The pattern is basically the same as the other one on this page, but it doesn't make removal of whitespace an extra step, but does it in a single pattern instead:

[image: Regex pattern \w*(are|finite|get|er)\w*\h*]

Regarding your comment:

> please modify your 2nd code so that if word https://www.get.co is in string whole word https://www.get.co must be removed

A word (`\w`) always matches the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Consequently, it will not match forward slashes, dots or colons. You will need to extend the character class as follows:

```
"#[\w/:.]*(%s)[\w/:.]*\h*#"
```

**As per performance:** benchmark it against some of your input.

Comment: As my strings are user provided and are about 4096 characters long, can you please guide me which answer is more efficient with respect of speed and memory usage

Comment: Do you mean your 2nd version is more efficient?

Comment: @DMP Please benchmark/profile in your scenario to see which suits your app context best.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon, I am not good in making regex please modify your 2nd code so that if word `https://www.get.co` is in string whole word `https://www.get.co` must be removed, currently it removes only `get` and remaining `https://www..co` is left in string, Regards

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon for your time, I think \S should also work.